# Insert the records into table when edit link is clicked Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a report with an edit link. The Edit link is Id. This report retrieves records from different databases.

My requirement is to insert those records into my database when the edit link is clicked. Please find the image below.

I need to insert these two records into my database table on clicking on the edit link.

How do I perform this in APEX?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would rather have another dedicated column on this report that does the required action than use an Edit link which is primarily used to drill down to a record in detail.

You can follow this [article](https://apexoracleblog.wordpress.com/2018/05/18/how-to-include-a-button-and-update-records-in-an-interactive-report-without-dynamic-action/) to achieve the desired action by creating a button on a report which performs DML action. Just make sure to accommodate the necessary changes to meet your needs.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't help

Comment: How does it not help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another perspective on solving this problem

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html

Comment: Sorry this doesn't help

Comment: In what way doesn't it help? Help us help you.